# Iframe not loading every time

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

I'm having a problem with displaying an `iframe` in my page. I am trying to use google docs to preview documents (doc, docx, pdf) from my server. Currently, I am using the following code (I've removed the URL for safety reasons):

```
<iframe src='//docs.google.com/viewer?url=&amp;embedded=true' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0' 
allowtransparency='true' style='position:relative';>Loading ...</iframe>"
```

The `iframe` loads perfectly 4 out of 5 times and when it doesn't load I get a blank `iframe` with empty DOM and no errors in the console. I've tested this with Chrome, Opera, FireFox, Edge and I got the same result with each one. I am really frustrated because I am losing a whole day trying to fix this problem.

I've tried to replace `iframe` with `object` like this:

```
<object type="text/html" data="My_Url_Here" style="width:100%; height:300px"></object>
```

And I got the same exact result. Has anyone run the same problem? I am using Joomla CMS. I am open to suggestions for `js` libraries or Joomla addons that will help me with displaying documents from the server.

Comment: How often are you refreshing the page? It might potentially be a usage limit being applied by Google.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital I'll try with a different URL. You may be right. I am refreshing quite often in order to "test" if it's working, but that may be my problem....

Comment: Try to run as a test a window.open()  after the <iframe>, (both pointing to the doc). If both fails, the problem is in the google docs engine. If only fails the iframe, the probem is in your server. At least you will know where to point.

Comment: There are more than one tab in the console: Have a look in the network console too - it could be there is a header showing why the response is empty without showing a console error.

Comment: Old post but possible hint - session timeout on google signin: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/tLVhGbITFMk;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/authorid$3AAPn2wQdrY64f8Hhty3gjmYDhipsb1CDsZqnJruCufFQ36o7JPVtE21X9iMiY06det0z7MtlTgEIR%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false

Comment: It works fine for me